# Profile image cache with glide?

Tags: android, profile, android-glide

I use Glide to load the image in profile screen. When I pick an image form camera or gallery and then I upload this image to amazon s3.

But Glide loads the same link more than once. Glide doesn't know image has changed. It shows the old image.

I tried using `diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)` but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've a problem with your link. Please check if the proper link for the image (i.e. the latest uploaded profile picture url) is passed to the `load` function.

`diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)` should work fine. I think you're passing the same old url here.